# Topology in $\Bbb {R}^n$ Proof Exercise

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Given set A$\ \subset \Bbb {R}^n$ and set B$\ \subset \Bbb {R}^n$, we define A+B={$\text{ a+b such that a $\in$ A and b $\in$ B}\}$.Prove:  $$\text{a) If A closed set, B compact set then A+B is a closed set}$$ $$\text{b) If A,B are compact sets then A+B is a compact set}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint for b): write $A+B$ as a continuous image of $A\times B \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a metric space, we consider closeness and compactness from the point of view of sequences. Let $\{y_n\}$ be a sequence in $A+B$, than $y_n$ can be written as $a_n+b_n$ where $a_n\in A$, $b_n\in B$.
First we want to show that if $y_n$ converges to a certain $y$, than $y$ is an element of $A+B$. The hypothesis tells us that $a_n+b_n \rightarrow y$. Now because $B$ is compact there exists a $b\in B$ such that $b_n\rightarrow b$. Now $a_n \rightarrow y-b$ and for closedness of $A$ we deduce that $y-b\in A$. Call $a=y-b$, then $y=a+b$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. So $y\in A+B$ implies that $A+B$ is closed.
Second we want to show that if $\{y_n= a_n+b_n\}$ is a sequence of $A+B$, then it admits a converging subsequence. From $\{a_n\}\in A$ we can take a converging subsequence $\{a_{n_j}\}$, so $y_{n_j} = a_{n_j}+b_{n_j}$. From $\{b_{n_j}\}\in B$ we can take a converging subsequence $\{b_{n_{j_k}}\}$, so $y_{n_{j_k}} = a_{n_{j_k}}+b_{n_{j_k}}\rightarrow y$, so $A+B$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you very much! Super clear.

Comment: Nitpick: for the fisrt proof, there is a *subsequence* of the $b_n$ that converges to some $b \in B$. You then have to work in that subsequence.

Comment: As an alternative to the last one: $f(x,y) = x+y$ is continuous and $A \times B$ is compact, hence so is $f[A \times B] = A + B$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for a)

Take any convergent sequence $\{a_k+b_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ where $a_k\in A$ and $b_k\in B$.

We can pick out a convergent subsequence of $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ denoted $\{b_{k_j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ (why?). Say $b_{k_j}\rightarrow b$. What can you now say about $\{a_{k_j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$?

Comment: How can you know that a convergent sequence $\{a_k+b_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ exists with the conditions you specified? Answering the why $\{b_{k_j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ exists as a convergent sequence, would be because B is a bounded set, therefore $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$  would be bounded and would therefore have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Any sequence in $A+B$ will be a sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ where $x_k = a_k+b_k$ where $a_k\in A$ and $b_k\in B$. In general any element $x\in A+B$ is of the form $a+b$.

Comment: Right, but how do you know a convergent one exists?

Comment: A set is closed if and only if every convergent sequence has its limit in the set. Therefore to prove that a $A+$ is closed we consider an ARBITRARY sequence and prove that its limit lies in $A+B$.